# Is it possible to dynamically enumerate all arrays in VB .NET?

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net

I have a lot of arrays in a web module I'm writing and I will be adding more as time goes on.  I would like to dynamically enumerate all arrays to search and update them.  Is this possible?  Snippet of code below:

```
Private EMASCFee() As String = {0, 1, "12345679", "MASC Debt SetOff Fees"}
Private EMSPen() As String = {2, 3, "987654312", "Medicare EMS Late Penalties"}
Private Beach() As String = {4, 5, "110022233", "Beach Services"}

Private allCodes() As Array 'Holds all Codes Arrays

Private Sub addArrays()    
    'Adds all Codes String Arrays together into 1 Array  *** Add NEW string arrays to the end of allCodes ***
    allCodes = {EMASCFee, EMSPen, Beach}
End Sub
```

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
Private EMASCFee() As String = {0, 1, "12345679", "MASC Debt SetOff Fees"}
Private EMSPen() As String = {2, 3, "987654312", "Medicare EMS Late Penalties"}
Private Beach() As String = {4, 5, "110022233", "Beach Services"}

Private allCodes() As Array 'Holds all Codes Arrays

Private Sub addArrays()    
    For each myArray as Array in ModuleName
        allCodes = {allCodes, myArray}
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you use an array after all? A Struct seems more reasonable to me. You already have the `allCodes` array. What more are you looking for?

Comment: You mean, using reflection?

Comment: @NicoSchertler, I am attempting to simplify entry of new codes by adding each one in their own string array and I have 45+ codes added this way.  Would I be able to add the structs to the allCodes array and search/update each?

Comment: @Jodrell, I've never used reflection before.  Would that be a good way to enumerate all of the existing String Arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to stick to the arrays, here is a way to do it:

```
Module Codes
    Private EMASCFee() As String = {0, 1, "12345679", "MASC Debt SetOff Fees"}
    Private EMSPen() As String = {2, 3, "987654312", "Medicare EMS Late Penalties"}
    Private Beach() As String = {4, 5, "110022233", "Beach Services"}

    Public Function GetAllCodes() As String()()
        Dim t = Type.GetType("WindowsApplication1.Codes") 'Change this to your project namespace
        Dim members = t.GetFields(Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Static)
        Dim result As New List(Of String())
        For Each m In members
            If m.FieldType = GetType(String()) Then
                result.Add(m.GetValue(Nothing))
            End If
        Next
        Return result.ToArray()
    End Function
End Module
```

However, I really recommend using a struct and generic lists instead of arrays. The overall concept would be the same.

Comment: I did have a format similar to the struct (though not a struct), but my manager wanted a simplified way of adding each group of values, that's why I went with the arrays.  This way he can add a single line with all the values, and now (thanks to you) he won't need to remember to add the string array to the allCodes array.  Thanks for the help!